# CouchDB view for mining automated test results

Tags: couchdb

I'm considering using CouchDB to store automated test results over time. I would store each test result as something like:

```
{ 
  testId: 123,
  passed: false,
  executionDate: "2013-06-05T09:58:34.881Z"
}
```

How could I construct a view to find tests that have been failing for the longest? I want to get a list of tests ordered by "most recent pass time" (oldest to newest), and a list of tests that have never passed. Is this practical in CouchDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to make this sort of query work efficiently in CouchDB.